# 2 jpanels but dont know how to control them

Tags: java, swing, applet, jpanel, layout-manager

Hey im trying to make a weather applet but i dont understand j panels every single time the one overlays the other heres what i want it to look like in the end

[image]

After i get this part of code i will be making an if else satement that draws an image dependent on "Season"

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Test21 extends JApplet
{
    JPanel jPanel1, jPanel2;
    JButton Enter , Exit;
    JTextField location;
    JLabel city;
    JRadioButton time;
    JComboBox Seasons;

    Random rand = new Random ();
    int P = rand.nextInt (100) + 1; //Random Precipitation
    int H = rand.nextInt (50) + 1; //Random Heat

    /** Initializes the applet Test02 */
    public void init ()
    {
                       jPanel2 = new DrawingPanel ();

        getContentPane ().setLayout (null);


        //);

        getContentPane ().add (jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setBounds (20, 20, 320, 240);




        jPanel1 = new DrawingPanel();       

        getContentPane ().setLayout (null);

        jPanel1.setBackground (new java.awt.Color (255, 255, 255));
        //);

        getContentPane ().add (jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setBounds (20, 20, 320, 240);   
        getContentPane() .setLayout (new FlowLayout ());

        Enter =new JButton ("Enter");
        Exit =new JButton ("exit");



        city = new JLabel ("What city?");
        location = new JTextField (20); //location entry field


        Seasons  = new JComboBox ();
        Seasons.addItem ("Summer");
        Seasons.addItem ("Fall");
        Seasons.addItem ("Winter");
        Seasons.addItem ("Spring");


        time = new JRadioButton ("check if night?");


       getContentPane().add (city);
       getContentPane().add (location);
       getContentPane().add (Seasons);
       getContentPane().add (time);


    }     

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint (g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawLine (10, 70, 70, 10);

    }    

    private class DrawingPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel
    {
        public void paint (Graphics g)
        {
            super.paint (g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            drawBars (g);
        }
    }
    public void drawBars (Graphics g)
    {
        //Precipitation Bar
        g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.drawRect (40, 170, 100, 20); //outline of bar
        g.setColor (Color.blue);
        g.fillRect (40 + 1, 170 + 4, P, 14); //indicator bar (+4 puts space beetween outline bar)

        //Temparature Bar
        g.setColor (Color.red);
        g.fillRect (170 + 4, 50, 14, 100); //Covers in
        g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.drawRect (170, 50, 20, 100); //outline of bar
        g.setColor (Color.white);
        g.fillRect (170 + 4, 50 + 1, 16, 100 - H); //indicator bar (+4 puts space beetween outline bar)
    }



}
```

this is a big mark in my class please dont give me the why teachers shouldn't teach CS or any of that it dosn't help me i use Ready java while programming also so if you could try to keep same packets i'm very inexperienced and lost but i need this done by monday and have been working on it for a long time

ok so im trying a new file with border layout andill create the classes bellow and try to call them i guess?

```
    public class Final
{

    JPanel jPanel1, jPanel2;
    JButton Enter, Exit;
    JTextField location;
    JLabel city;
    JRadioButton time;
    JComboBox Seasons;

    Random rand = new Random ();
    int P = rand.nextInt (100) + 1; //Random Precipitation
    int H = rand.nextInt (50) + 1; //Random Heat
    public void init ()
    {
        JPanel contentPane = getContentPane ();




        contentPane.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        contentPane.add (locationGui, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add (temp, BorderLayout.EAST);
        contentPane.add (Percip (g), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        contentPane.add (image, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }


public void drawPercip (Graphics g)
    {
        //Precipitation Bar
        g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.drawRect (40, 170, 100, 20); //outline of bar
        g.setColor (Color.blue);
        g.fillRect (40 + 1, 170 + 4, P, 14); //indicator bar (+4 puts space beetween outline bar)
    }
}
```

This is now the code im working with i got the location gui parts in but when i trydoing tlabel = new DrawingPanel(); it says it cant be done so how would i bring that graphic in? and im pretty sure ill need to be using actionlistener so ill have to add it in with implements a bit later

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Final2 extends JFrame
{
    //Panels
    JPanel locationGui = new JPanel ();
    JPanel temp = new JPanel ();
    JPanel percip = new JPanel ();
    JPanel image = new JPanel ();
    //Location gui components
    JButton Enter, Exit;
    JTextField location;
    JLabel city;
    JRadioButton time;
    JComboBox Seasons;
    //bar # genertor
    Random rand = new Random ();
    int P = rand.nextInt (100) + 1; //Random Precipitation
    int H = rand.nextInt (50) + 1; //Random Heat
    public Final2 ()
    {
        init ();

    }


    public void init ()
    {
        Font font = new Font ("impact", Font.PLAIN, 20);
        //________________________________________________new panel____________________
        locationGui.setBackground (Color.RED);
        JLabel guiLabel = new JLabel ("");
        guiLabel.setFont (font);

        Enter = new JButton ("Enter");
        Exit = new JButton ("exit");



        city = new JLabel ("What city?");
        location = new JTextField (20); //location entry field


        Seasons = new JComboBox ();
        Seasons.addItem ("Summer");
        Seasons.addItem ("Fall");
        Seasons.addItem ("Winter");
        Seasons.addItem ("Spring");


        time = new JRadioButton ("check if night?");


        locationGui.add (city);
        locationGui.add (location);
        locationGui.add (Seasons);
        locationGui.add (time);



        locationGui.add (guiLabel);


        //________________________________________________new panel____________________
        temp.setBackground (Color.BLUE);
        temp.setLayout (new GridBagLayout ());
        JLabel tempLabel = new JLabel ("Temp");
        tempLabel.setFont (font);
        temp.add (tempLabel);

        //________________________________________________new panel____________________
        percip.setBackground (Color.GREEN);
        JLabel pLabel = new JLabel ("Percip");
        pLabel.setFont (font);
        percip.add (pLabel);

        //________________________________________________new panel____________________
        image.setBackground (Color.ORANGE);
        image.setLayout (new GridBagLayout ());
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel ("Image");
        imageLabel.setFont (font);
        image.add (imageLabel);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane ();

        contentPane.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        contentPane.add (locationGui, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add (temp, BorderLayout.EAST);
        contentPane.add (percip, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        contentPane.add (image, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setContentPane (contentPane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize (400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        setVisible (true);
    }


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable ()
        {

            public void run ()
            {
                new Final2 ();
            }
        }


        );
    }


    private class DrawingPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel
    {
        public void paint (Graphics g)
        {
            super.paint (g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            drawPercip (g);
        }


    }


    public void drawPercip (Graphics g)
    {
        //Precipitation Bar
        g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.drawRect (40, 170, 100, 20); //outline of bar
        g.setColor (Color.blue);
        g.fillRect (40 + 1, 170 + 4, P, 14); //indicator bar (+4 puts space beetween outline bar)
    }


    public void drawTemp (Graphics g)
    {
        //Temparature Bar
        g.setColor (Color.red);
        g.fillRect (170 + 4, 50, 14, 100); //Covers in
        g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.drawRect (170, 50, 20, 100); //outline of bar
        g.setColor (Color.white);
        g.fillRect (170 + 4, 50 + 1, 16, 100 - H); //indicator bar (+4 puts space beetween outline bar)
    }




}
```

Comment: You first call setLayout(null) and then later you call setLayout(new FlowLayout()). Which one do you want to use? You should almost always use a layout (not a null layout), in which case calling setBounds() on your JPanel won't work. Instead, try calling setMinimumSize() and setPreferredSize(). Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: ok well i want the buttons as flow layout and im hoping to just keep the other as one frame i guess

Answer (score 3):

1. `JApplet` *has* no `paintComponent` method, so you're not actually overriding anything. As good practice, you should use the `@Override` annotation to make cure you are making a valid override. `JApplet` *does* have a `paint` method though.
2. Don't override `paint` in a `JPanel`. Instead override `paintComponent` and call `super.paintComponent`
3. Don't use null layouts. Swing is made to be used with LayoutManagers. See [**Laying out components in a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
4. As @KevinWorkman suggested, the layout you want is [**BorderLayout**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

---

**UPDATE** for your new post

1. getContentPane() return a `Container`. You can make it = a `JPanel`
2. You haven't declared any variables we can work with

See the example below to see how `BorderLayout` would work for your `Final` class.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Final extends JFrame{

    JPanel locationGui = new JPanel();
    JPanel temp = new JPanel();
    JPanel percip= new JPanel();
    JPanel image = new JPanel();
    public Final() {
        init();

    }

    public void init() {
        Font font = new Font("impact", Font.PLAIN, 20);

        locationGui.setBackground(Color.RED);
        JLabel guiLabel = new JLabel("Location Gui");
        guiLabel.setFont(font);
        locationGui.add(guiLabel);

        temp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        temp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel tempLabel = new JLabel("Temp");
        tempLabel.setFont(font);
        temp.add(tempLabel);

        percip.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        JLabel gLabel = new JLabel("Percip");
        gLabel.setFont(font);
        percip.add(gLabel);

        image.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        image.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel("Image");
        imageLabel.setFont(font);
        image.add(imageLabel);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(locationGui, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(temp, BorderLayout.EAST);
        contentPane.add(percip, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        contentPane.add(image, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Final();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE

to your new edit

- When you do `temp = new DrawingPanel()`, it works, but there are two problems

  1. There is no preffered size to the panel, to the panel will only adhere to the dimension defined in the `BorderLayout` of the frame. To fix that, override the `getPreferredSize` of the `DrawingPanel`
  2. The `fillRect` doesn't show because it's the same color as the background.

Here are the fixes to your code.

```
private class DrawingPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        drawPercip(g);
    }
    @Override 
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 400);
    }
}

public void drawPercip(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(40, 170, 100, 20);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(40 + 1, 170 + 4, P, 14); 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand much of what you side but im gonna try the border layout idk how im gonna add the rest of components though i guess ill make the g.draw methods at the bottom and call them into each area but i also don't understand how id do that =S

Comment: @overide is apparently an illegal token

Comment: `@Override` .... The method has to actually override another method, or the @Override will give an error. That's why it is useful. If you are not declaring the method signature correctly of an attempted overriding of a method, you will get flagged. Which method exactly are you trying to override?

Comment: ok a did the code i scraped overide atm  and i got the location gui in but how would i do the graphics for temp i posted edit above and tried  using it as tpanel = new drawingPanel

Comment: And what happens when you do that?

Comment: ok i changed it to that but now im getting errors again on the @Override "illegal token" and "unexpected symbols ignored"

Answer (score 1):

The image you posted can be achieved using a BorderLayout. Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

```
JPanel contentPane = getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
contentPane.add(locationGui, BorderLayout.NORTH);
contentPane.add(temp, BorderLayout.EAST);
contentPane.add(percip, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
contentPane.add(image, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Ok so to make it a bit easier for me to follow a started a new file and posted what i tried above but im still so lost

Comment: @CurtisSpence What are you confused about? I highly suggest starting smaller and working your way up. [Here](http://StaticVoidGames.com/tutorials/swing/Layouts.jsp) is a tutorial on layouts including BorderLayout.

Comment: i wish i could do that but itsa final project and i just have been drawing a blank to what i've learned